# what does strtok(NULL, "\n") do?

Tags: c, strtok

> The C library function char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim) breaks string str into a series of tokens using the delimiter delim.

What happens when you put `s = strtok(NULL, "\n")`? what does it mean splitting null by `\n`?

Comment: Tried [`man strtok`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)?

Comment: Or [cppreference.com/.../strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok)?

Comment: "In subsequent calls, str should be NULL, and saveptr should be unchanged since the previous call". Maybe you look at "subsequent call" - see lines above for other `strtok`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a basic question that can be answered by reading any basic C book/tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean splitting NULL by `\n`.

If you pass a non-NULL value, you are asking it to start tokenizing the passed string.

If you pass a NULL value, you are asking to continue tokenizing the same string as before (usually used in loops).

Example:

```
int main(void)
{
   char *token, string[] = "a string, of,; ;;;,tokens";

   token = strtok(string, ", ;");
   do
   {
      printf("token: \"%s\"\n", token);
   }
   while (token = strtok(NULL, ", ;"));
}
```

Result:

```
token: "a"                                                                                                                                                   
token: "string"                                                                                                                                              
token: "of"                                                                                                                                                  
token: "tokens"
```

Comment: If no such token exists, `token = strtok(string, ", ;")` will return `NULL` and `printf("token: \"%s\"\n", token);` will attempt to print a `NULL` character.